# Adobe AEM (CQ) 5.6 Remove renditions workflow

Tags: workflow, aem

I'm looking for a way (preferably a workflow) that removes/cleans renditions!
My problem is that over time I have loads of images with renditions that are no longer used.

Is there a good way to clean this and "reclaim" my disk space? :)

Answer (score 1):

Though i would like to suggest you sling servlet route to remove as you will have more control over what should be deleted and from which path.

You can reuse some of the code from below as well.

I created a sample program a few weeks back to remove renditions except the original one whenever a new image was added and i was using workflows:

The code below was a component. A workflow was created and this class was then added as a process step to a workflow and the same workflow was set in any launcher and event type was created.

Basically, i used Query builder api and workflow api and was able to achieve the same. If you use servlet way as suggested you can take path as a parameter and then use query builder api to locate the renditions folder and then iterate over the same and remove the nodes.

Sample values that will be extracted via query builder:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=%2fcontent%2fdam%2fgeometrixx%2ficons&property=jcr%3aprimaryType&property.1_value=nt%3afolder



public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfsession, MetaDataMap args)
            throws WorkflowException {
            try {
                resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
                WorkflowData workflowData = item.getWorkflowData();
                String path = workflowData.getPayload().toString();
                path = path.replace("/jcr:content/renditions", "");
                session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("path", path);
                map.put("property", "jcr:primaryType");
                map.put("property.1_value", "nt:folder");
                Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
                SearchResult result = query.getResult();
                List<Hit> hits = result.getHits();
                Resource renditionResource = resourceResolver.resolve(hits.get(0).getPath());   
                Iterator<Resource> reneditionIterator = renditionResource.listChildren();
                while(reneditionIterator.hasNext()){
                    Resource specificResource=  reneditionIterator.next();
                    Node renditionNode = specificResource.adaptTo(Node.class);
                    if(!renditionNode.getName().equals("original")){
                        renditionNode.remove();
                    }
                }

            } catch (LoginException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Servlet

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = slingHTTPrequest.getResourceResolver();
            String path = slingHTTPrequest.getParameter("path");
            session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("path", path);
            map.put("property", "jcr:primaryType");
            map.put("property.1_value", "nt:folder");
            Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
            SearchResult result = query.getResult();
            List<Hit> hits = result.getHits();
            for(Hit hit: hits){
                Resource renditionResource = resourceResolver.resolve(hit.getPath());   
                Iterator<Resource> reneditionIterator = renditionResource.listChildren();
                 while(reneditionIterator.hasNext()){
                    Resource specificResource=  reneditionIterator.next();
                    Node renditionNode = specificResource.adaptTo(Node.class);
                    LoggerUtil.debugLog(this.getClass(),"Node name will be {}",renditionNode.getName());
                    if(!renditionNode.getName().equals("original")){
                        LoggerUtil.debugLog(this.getClass(), "removing rendition, parent node name is{}",renditionNode.getParent().getParent().getParent().getName());
                        renditionNode.remove();
                    }
                 }
            }
```